# Current month Minus 1 month

Tags: php

How do i properly minus 1 month for the current month ?

```
$current_month1  = date('m'); 
$current_month  = $current_month1-1;
echo $current_month;

//current ouput
6
//desired output
06
```

Comment: Read the docs : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php .

Comment: Numeric values don't have leading zeros. If you want leading zeros, format the number upon output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in combination with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this.

```
echo date('m', strtotime('last month')); // 06
```

Answer (score 3):

check the following:

```
$now = new \DateTime("now");
$past = $now->modify("-1 month");
```

[DateTime::modify docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Also you can do it using DateInterval, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) has example.

Answer (score 1):

The `m` operator in `date` will get you:

```
echo date('m', strtotime('now - 1 month'));
```

Gives `06`.